# Test if all methods of a Remote interface throw RemoteException

Tags: java, reflection, junit, rmi, remoteexception

When working with RMI (Remote Method Invocation), it is required for all methods defined in interfaces extending `Remote` to contain `RemoteException` in their `throws` clause.

For example, see the following `Computing` interface from [this RMI tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/designing.html).

```
public interface Compute extends Remote {
    <T> T executeTask(Task<T> t) throws RemoteException;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler does not check if the methods are defined correctly, instead an exception is thrown during the execution when the program encounters a method in a `Remote` interface that does not throw `RemoteException`.

It would be much better if such problems were discovered before the program is actually run. How can one write a test for that condition?

---

**EDIT:** I added a sample code to demonstrate the problem.

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>rmic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

`src/main/java/test/RemoteExample.java`

```
package test;
import java.rmi.Remote;
public interface RemoteExample extends Remote {
  // the method does not throw RemoteException
  void action();
}
```

`src/test/java/test/RemoteExampleTest.java`

```
package test;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RemoteExampleTest {
  @Test
  public void test1() throws RemoteException {
    RemoteExample example = new RemoteExample() {
      public void action() {
        // do nothing
      }
    };
    // this fails
    RemoteExample exported = (RemoteExample) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(example, 0);
  }
}
```

`mvn test` fails, because the method `RemoteExample.action()` is declared in a `Remote` interface but does not throw `RemoteException`, therefore it can't be exported. However, if you add `@Ignore` before the test, maven build ends successfully, which implies that the condition was not tested.

I see a solution to write a custom test that would look at each `Remote` interface and would check if every method throws `RemoteException`, using reflection. But I believe there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

`rmic` checks it. You could incorporate `rmic` into your build. Make sure to delete the `_stub.class` files afterwards if you want to use dynamic stubs.

Comment: I use Maven for building the project, so I added `rmic-maven-plugin` to the dependency list. But the condition is still not tested during the compilation. Is there anything specific to do in order to force `rmic` test the condition?

Comment: It does so by default. Are you sure it's executing? and that you have `Remote` interfaces that should fail? NB you run it on the remote objects, not the interfaces.

Comment: The point is that I want to test interfaces. Remote objects do not need to throw `RemoteException`. I do not think that in my configuration any tests other than mine are executing. I added a code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The point is that `rmic` already tests it, as I already stated. I'm aware that you run it on remote objects, but if the remote interface(s) it implements has methods that don't throw `RemoteException` it will complain. You don't need to do anything further.